# Copy a Folder from Internal Storage to Removable Storage (SD Card)

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I’m trying to copy media contents created by my App (under DCIM folder in internal storage (/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/MyApp) to a folder inside my SD card.

So I’d like to check if DCIM folder exist inside sd card, if not create the folder and copy the directory and all its contents to SD card. Since this would be a long operation I was thinking of doing it inside an asynctask.

For the life of me, I can’t seem to be able to do anything on SD card. I see that for whatever reason google decided to change SD access framework with every major iteration. So I started looking into StorageManager since that seems to be the most up to date way.

However, it seems that I’d need to manage it inside an activity and potentially I’d like to do this inside an AsyncTask, would there be a way of doing this inside AsyncTask?

I’m bit confused about how to use StorageManager in this manner, and to be honest I don’t even know it can be done so I was wondering if you have any idea of how to go around doing this?

I’d really appreciate a sample code snippet for copying a folder from Internal storage to SD card.

Thanks!

EDIT: below is a snippet of code how I was trying to copy the folders from internal storage to the apps own storage inside the sdcard:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
    String[] storageDirs = getExternalStorageDirectories();
    Log.d(TAG, Arrays.toString(storageDirs));


    File[] externalDirs = m_context.getExternalFilesDirs(null);
    Log.d(TAG, Arrays.toString(externalDirs));

    File internalDir = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myApp/"); // /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myApp/
    File sdcardDir = new File(m_context.getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1] + "/TEST/");

    Long totalSize = dirSize(internalDir);
    Log.d(TAG, "Source Directory Size: " + totalSize);

    try {
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(internalDir, sdcardDir);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error while copying directories! Aborting file transfer!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: "I see that for whatever reason google decided to change SD access framework with every major iteration" -- there was only one significant change in one Android version (4.4) to how [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) works. Everything else (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, `StorageVolume`) were incremental changes to this.

Comment: "I’d need to manage it inside an activity" -- you need to ask the user for access in an activity. Once you have access, your actual `DocumentFile` work to traverse the tree and your `ContentResolver` work to copy the content could be done in a background thread of some form. "I’m bit confused about how to use StorageManager in this manner" -- I would recommend `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, for user flexibility (to choose any destination tree) and for greater compatibility (works on Android 5.1+).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your reply! Would I need to ask for permission every single time? If I were to check for permission inside the asynctask like:
 `m_context.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` returns true so I think I already got the permission.

Comment: No. You never have to ask for any permission. Just start experimenting with Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. And you have already permission for your source.

Comment: "Would I need to ask for permission every single time?" -- not necessarily. You can [call `takePersistableUriPermission()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)) to get durable access. Until the user does something major (e.g., deletes the tree), you should be able to continue using it indefinitely.

Comment: @greenapps I see, and just curious, would it be possible to use Document Tree without prompting user to select the folder? I'd like to handle all that under the hood if possible, so that all user would have to do is to press a button to indicate they want contents to be copied to their sd card and nothing else.

Comment: If you can make the user choose once the root of the micro SD card then you can write on the card everywhere without further user interaction. But you should let the user choose once.

Comment: And if the user puts another micro SD card you should let choose him again.

Comment: Before you start you should have a look at getExternalFilesDirs(). It might return two File instances. The second one would be an app specific directory on the micro SD card where you can write and copy in the usual way.

Comment: @greenapps I was using getExternalFilesDirs to get the path to SD Card and tried to used Apache's `FileUtils.copyDirectory` but for some reason that didn't work copying folder from SD card to apps internal storage.

Comment: Did you use getExternalFilesDir() or getExternalFilesDirs()?

Comment: By the way: copying from card is mostly possible. As we often can read all. Copying to is not possibke as card not writable.

Comment: @greenapps, getExternalFilesDirs interestingly, it does create all the subfolders but when it comes to transferring actual file it throws `java.io.FileNotFoundException: path/to/the/file (Invalid argument)`

Comment: Then show your code so we see what you do. Put the code in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: @greenapps edited my original post to include the source code.

Comment: Without seeing the code for `FileUtils.copyDirectory()` i cannot comment.

Comment: `Log.e(TAG, "Error while copying directories! Aborting file transfer!");` You are throwing away valuble info about the exception. You should also log `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: `+ "/TEST/"` Is that directory created to begin with? Or does it already stop creating that directory?

Comment: @greenapps it creates any directories that doesn't exist, so running this code for the first time, it would create TEST directory inside Android/data/myApp/files.

Comment: Wel if it can create directories then it should be able to copy files too. Why dont you post the code?

Comment: `it throws java.io.FileNotFoundException: path/to/the/file (Invalid argument)` Is that at reading the source file or writing the destination file?

Comment: @greenapps FileUtils.copyDirectory is Apache's own implementation and the source can be found [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)
Anything else I'm doing in that AsyncTask isn't really relevant so I just omitted it. 
If I were to change sdcardDir to a directory inside internal storage (like DCIM) it works flawlessly. It's just weird that it can create folders but can't copy the actual files for sd card..

Comment: @greenapps reading the source, but source is there since it can read perfectly fine for internal to internal copy